# Combine all variables into one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five variables in my JavaScript code. I want to combine all these variable into one single variable.

My five variables:

```
var description = $("#description").val();
var keywords =  $("#keywords").val();
var author = $("#author").val();
var robots = $("#robots").val();
var revisit_after = $("#revisitafter").val();
```

I want all these variables to be combined into one variable, like this:

```
var all_fields = title,description,keywords,author,robots,revisit_after ;
```

If this worked, I could easily validate my input fields like this:

```
if(all_fields == "")
{
alert('Empty Field detected');
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="Title" id="title"><br> 
<input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="Description" id="description"><br> 
<input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="author" id="author"><br> 
<input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="Keywords" id="keywords"><br>
```

Is there any way to them into a single variable?

Comment: And if you combine thos values in a javascript object??

Comment: What does your HTML look like for declaring these nodes?

Comment: string concatenation: `title + description + ...`

Comment: I think you probably need to read a beginners tutorial and learn about Objects and Arrays, which are the JavaScript composite types.

Comment: I don't think concatenation will help you in this instance.

Comment: But there's no shorthand for the comparison you want to do. Close as you'll come will be something like `if (!array.every(Boolean)) { alert() }`

Comment: @esqew 

here is HTML
 <input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="Title" id="title"><br>
    <input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="Description" id="description"><br>
    <input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="author" id="author"><br>
    <input type="text" class="text_boxes" placeholder="Keywords" id="keywords"><br>

Comment: Actually since it seems he's wanting to check if all are empty, it would seem that the concatenation would be a solution that would work in this specific case.

Comment: @cookiemonster : Mmmm.. Oke .. Thnks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: @ShifarShifz: There's an edit button under your question. Please use it to post additional code.

Comment: @ShifarShifz: While you're there, perhaps REMOVE THE SHOUTING. :-) Also clarify: Do you want to check if *any* of them is blank, or if *all* of them are blank?

Comment: Not sure what else you need to do with these, but you could enjoy some nice code reduction if you put the IDs in an Array to begin with. `var ids = ["description","keywords","author","robots","revisit_after"]; var values = $("#" + ids.join(",#")).map(function(i, el) { return el.value; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting them all into an array manually, you can use jQuery to enumerate them all based on their field type and verify they are not empty:

```
function check() {
    $("input[type='text']").not(".no-verify").each(function (i, element) {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            alert("Empty field detected!");
        }
    });
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4m9bA/2/)

Advantages of this approach:

1. Add/delete fields as you please.
2. Easy to add field types to check for and custom code to run for each.
3. Easy to change what constitutes "empty" and what doesn't.
4. Exclude fields from being checked for an empty value by adding the class `no-verify`.

Comment: This is great!! Thank yu so much.. Muaaww :*

Comment: @ShifarShifz Just remember, if you have a field that CAN be empty, this still 'validates' it.  So you will have to use a `.not()` in this if that's the case

Comment: @ntgCleaner great idea- I've updated my answer with a usage of `.not` in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing if you're allowed to change this or not, I would personally write a new array at the end of whatever you're doing, something like this:

```
var arr = [];
var empty = false;
var description = $("#description").val();
var keywords =  $("#keywords").val();
var author = $("#author").val();
var robots = $("#robots").val();
var revisit_after = $("#revisitafter").val();

arr.push(description, keywords, author, robots, revisit_after);
```

Then check your array

```
arr.each(function(i){
    if(arr[i] == ""){
        empty = true;
    }   
});

if(empty) console.log("Something is missing");
```

or if you like your code faster, use a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= arry.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == ""){
        empty = true;
    }  
}

if(empty) console.log("Something is missing");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that they all have a value, use `&&`:

```
var all_fields = title && description && keywords && author && robots && revisit_after;
if(!all_fields)
{
    alert('Empty Field detected');
}
```

This works because `&&` checks that a value is "truthy" meaning it has some sort of value (read more on this, it's a bit complex). Therefore, if any of them are empty, it would make `all_fields` false. A limitation would be if one of them were to have the value `0`, which is technically a value, but is not "truthy". However, I believe jquery's `val()` always returns a string, and `"0"` *is* truthy.

Comment: @RobertRozas: Good example of a limitation. :-) *(Deleted my comment **half a second** before yours appeared...)*

Comment: *"I believe jquery's val() always returns a string..."* FWIW: `val` always returns as string (the value of the first element in the set) **if** there are any elements in the jQuery object (set) you call it on. It returns `undefined` if there aren't any elements in the set at all.

Comment: Anyway @xdumaine, your answer needs to be polished...also is the closest answer to the OP reqs(Edited:too late..)...

Comment: @RobertRozas It doesn't need to be polished. It's a SO answer. It provides an example of a basic feature of the language similar to what OP was trying to accomplish, not some code that's going to be committed and tested with all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try an object literal.

```
var all_fields = {
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "yada" : yada    
}
```

Comment: can i use this

if(all_fields ==""){alert('Some field missing!');}
.I am new in Js. dont knw much abt this. jus started to learn!